# Style attribute in firefox

Tags: javascript, css

i am using a piece of code in js as:-

```
span_1.style.width = '30%'

input_1.style.width = '40%';

td_1.style.cursor = 'hand';
```

where `span_1` , `input_1` , `td_1` are `span` , `input` , `td` objects, resp.

All are not working in firefox?Any suggestions...

Comment: Can you show us how you declare and find your variables/DOMElements?

Comment: btw. `cursor: hand` is a legacy style and not supported on many browsers, use `cursor: pointer` instead

Comment: Can you provide some more code context ? HTML, JS, CSS. Or create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: What do you mean with *not working*? What is the result you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers put all elements with an id as properties in the `window` object so that you can access them directly, but this is not a web standard. Use the `getElementById` method to access elements:

```
document.getElementById('span_1').style.width = '30%';

document.getElementById('input_1').style.width = '40%';

document.getElementById('td_1').style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure, but I guess you'll have to display them as 'block' first, since spans are inline-elements. Also, the parent element should have a width set.

so in css: display: block;

//edit:

display: inline-block;

may even be better.

Answer (score 0):

First: the `hand` value for `cursor` is Microsoft's proprietary implementation of what every other browser calls `pointer.` I think you have to go back to IE5 to find an IE that doesn't support `pointer` so use that instead.

If you want to support browsers that don't understand `pointer` then change the `.className` instead and have a style predefined:

```
.foo { 
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Second: The width property does not apply to `display: inline` elements (which a `<span>` is by default). IE may get this wrong in quirks mode, which leads to many inconsistances. Make sure you are in [standards mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

If you are using a span, then change it to a block element, or style the display so it isn't inline (e.g. `display: inline-block;`).

Third: You don't specify how you get the reference to the elements in the respective variables. IE has a tendency to splurge global variables that match the id of any given element. This is non-standard and can't be relied upon. Make sure you get proper references. e.g.

```
var span_1 = document.getElementById('span_1');
```

Comment: I am creating three spans dynamically in JS and inserting them as child of a td ( also created dynamically and width being given ).So, i want to give them different widths viz. 40%, 22% , 38%.

Comment: Oh no. Not another "Let's draw a barchat with HTML" script? The solution is in the above though.

Comment: what i referred to as span_1 was span object.

Comment: document.getElementById('span_1').style.width = '30%';
This is also not working in firefox.

Comment: See the section that starts "Second"

Comment: I used span_1.style.display = 'block'; and similarly for other spans..But Then the span_1 is occupying the whole width available in td making the second one shift to second line and so on..So, i guess that does'nt serve the purpose.

Comment: span_1.style.display = 'inline-block' is working in firefox..thanks a lot for ur feedback..